# Generar Corres Aleatorios

Tags: java, random, queue

Hola Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio en Java me pide generar Correos de manera aleatoria y meterlo en una Queue y si el correo es spawm sacarlo de la queue. Los correo tiene que tener(Cuerpo,remitente,Asunto).Si en alguna de las partes del correo apara la palabra oferta es considerado spawm. Pero no he podido generar los correos con esos 3 datos y meterlo en la queue.
tengo esta idea pero no logro q funcione
//debe ser una funcion pero no se de q tipo y como hago para que lo genere

```
        String[] remitentes= {"Mama","papa","hermano"} ;
        String[] asuntos={"ofertas","aviso","revise"};
        String[] Cuerpo={"Compre ahora","Esta es una noticia","Esta Avisado"};
        String Remitente=remitentes[Mi_Helper.Random(remitentes.length)];
        String asunto=asuntos[Mi_Helper.Random(asuntos.length)];
        String cuerpo=Cuerpo[Mi_Helper.Random(Cuerpo.length)];
        return Correo(Remitente,asunto,cuerpo);`
```

Estoy usando una queue con programacion generica

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste Esteban , revisar [ask],saludos.

Comment: ¿que API estas usando para revisar los correos?